# vbo with 2D texture - real-time transparency issue

Tags: opengl, transparency, texture2d

I am working on a n-body code which models the dynamics of a stellar disk. In the rendering, there are two types of particles : "classic" particles ( whites in the below image) and "dark matter" particles (in blue).

Here's this image at the start of simulation :

[image]

Everything seems to be ok with transparency but if I zoom during the run, I notice that actually, some particles keeps the same intermediate color, i.e there are purple.

Here's an example on this image ( which is the stellar disk seen from the side) :

[image]

My main problem is so that I don't understand why the color doesn't change as a function of others particles which are behind. For example, I would like a white/blue particle to be partially shaded by the others blue/white particles, and in real-time.

I show you my drawPoints() function where I use transparency :

```
void drawPoints()
{
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE);
    glTexEnvi(GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL_TRUE);
    glEnable(GL_VERTEX_PROGRAM_POINT_SIZE_NV);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    //glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    glUseProgram(m_program);
    glUniform1f( glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "pointRadius"), m_particleRadius );
    glUniform1f( glGetUniformLocation(m_program, "pointScale"), m_pointScale );

    GLuint vbo_disk;

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_disk);
        glVertexPointer(4, GL_DOUBLE, 4*sizeof(double), pos);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numBodies_disk);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    GLuint vbo_halo;

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_halo);
        glVertexPointer(4, GL_DOUBLE, 4*sizeof(double), &pos[numBodies_disk]);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, numBodies_halo);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 

        glDisable(GL_BLEND);        
    glDisable(GL_POINT_SPRITE);
}
```

I tried to use `glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST )` but it draws 2D texture with black background squares.

Could you give me some clues to have this cumulated and partial transparency in real-time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you disable depth testing:

```
glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
```

Then, you may want to try different blending modes such as additive blending:

```
glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE );
```

While additive blending is really pretty, it may produce too much white which could defeat the purpose of this visualization. You may try lowering alpha values in `glColor4f`. Another solution would be to use blue and red particles to accentuate the difference.